# Como desabilitar comentários no Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou começando a estudar Angular (versão atual) e verifiquei que depois que os códigos todos são compilados, os comentários de informações de desenvolvimento que coloco nos arquivos `.ts` são replicados para os arquivos `.js` gerados pelo Angular. Esses comentários ficam disponíveis para leitura nos fontes da página gerada e exibida no browser. Preciso dos comentários por uma questão de documentação.

Tem alguma maneira de impedir que os comentários dos arquivos `.ts` sejam replicados para os arquivos `.js`?

Comment: Se vc fizer a build pra produção provavelmente não va aparecer.

Answer (score 1):

Não se preocupe com isso, quando fizer a build para produção(ng build --prod), os comentários serão descartados, veja o que é dito na [documentação](https://angular.io/guide/deployment): 
"Minification: removes excess whitespace, comments, and optional tokens."

Comment: Ah ok! Não cheguei lá ainda, mas agradeço a informação. Obrigado.